# Unique with its type?

Tags: java, class, types, unique

Every phone number must be unique with its type. They must be stored as two fields: phone type (work, home, cell) and number.
How can I write a class like that in java?
Is the constracter below true or not?

```
public class PhoneNumber {

   private int number;
   private String type;

public PhoneNumber(int number1,String type1){

    setNumber(number1);
    setType(type1);
}
```

Comment: Your data model should be independent of the constraints around user input.  You'd be better served putting that sort of validation check at another level (e.g. when you insert the value into a collection or other data store).  By the way - a phone number is not, and will never be, an actual numeral.

Comment: Type can be an enum as well.

Comment: As it stands this question does not provide enough information and is too broad. How are you maintaining uniqueness and how are new `PhoneNumber`s created?

Comment: Where are you ensuring the uniqueness of the phone number field? If it is within your setters, provide the code for them. The phone number shouldn't be stored as a int; use a String.

Comment: A `PhoneNumber` with its type and number is a piece of data. It is a _Business Rule_ that phone numbers should be unique within type, so that constraint doesn't belong in the PhoneNumber class.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like:

```
public class PhoneNumber {

    private int number;
    private String type;

    public static Map<Integer, PhoneNumber> knownNumbers = new HashMap<Integer, PhoneNumber>();

    public PhoneNumber(int number1,String type1) throws AlreadyExistsNumberException{
        validate(number1);
        this.number = number1;
        this.type = type1;

        knownNumbers.put(number, this);
    }



    private void validate(int number1) {
        if(knownNumbers.get(number1) != null){
            throw new AlreadyExistsNumberException("The number "+number1+" already exists");
        }
    }
}
```

And then, for example:

```
try{
    PhoneNumber number = new PhoneNumber(66666666, "Mobile");
}catch(AlreadyExistsNumberException e){
    //Deal with the problem
}
```

Of course there are several ways to solve this problem, you can also have an static method to check it, use a boolean method to see if it already exists, etc...

**EDIT**

Another alternative:

```
public class PhoneNumber {

    private int number;
    private String type;

    public static Map<Integer, PhoneNumber> knownNumbers = new HashMap<Integer, PhoneNumber>();

    public PhoneNumber(int number1,String type1){
        this.number = number1;
        this.type = type1;

        knownNumbers.put(number, this);
    }

    private static boolean validate(int number1) {
        return (knownNumbers.get(number1) == null);
    }
}
```

And it's usage:

```
int number = 66666666;
String type = "Cell";
if(validate(number))
    PhoneNumber phoneNumber = new PhoneNumber(number, type);
```

Comment: I know that there is controversy with the exception usage, but for me they fit with the problem, if we base on java documentation... "An exception is an event that occurs during the execution of a program that disrupts the normal flow of instructions." and this, in my opinion, can be considered that case.

Comment: @Makoto edited with a non-Exception alternative

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `ints` for your phone numbers. For one thing, phone numbers are 10 digits (all positive), so they could easily exceed the capacity of `int`. For another thing, phone numbers are just not integers... You'd never add or substract or multiply by a phone number.

Here's what it should look like:

```
public enum PhoneType { ... // fill in the possible phone types
}

public static final EnumMap<PhoneType, Set<String>> phoneNumbers = new EnumMap<PhoneType, Set<String>>();
```

You'll probably want to build some controls around these `DT`s to get/set phone numbers, but this should get you started

Comment: I don't see this relevant with the question

Comment: It is very relevant since the question is essentially "How do I create a class that represents a phone number for a contact?".